# How long should I wait between grout application and sealant?

Tags: sealing, grout, ceramic-tile

I'm about to apply grout to a ceramic-covered part of my bathroom (single step up to the bath tub). I'm using a pre-mixed grout and want to apply Sealer's Choice Gold sealant. The grout should not be exposed to water for at least 7 days (according to instructions) after setting, but when can I apply the sealant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [sealant data sheet](http://www.jamoinc.com/documents/ds_english/ami/SCG_RC_DataSheet_EN.pdf), you can seal new grout after 48 hours.

For me I would play it safe if I could (do you have to be able to use this bathroom?), if the grout says no water for 7 days I would wait that long before sealing.  That is probably overly cautious but then I don't get much work done during the week anyway so for me waiting until the next weekend is not a big deal.

After sealing I would wait 24 hours before getting it wet.

Comment: Not using the bathroom is not an option, unfortunately. I have the area covered with plastic, however, and that will have to serve.